# Is DocumentFile API broken on encrypted removable SD card on Samsung Galaxy S7?

Tags: android, encryption, samsung-mobile, samsung-galaxy, documentfile

I have created a **zero size file aaa.txt** on the root folder of the **UNENCRYPTED removable SD card**. The file aaa.txt has correct size 0 bytes when I [list all entries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RH1od.png) in the root folder with [DocumentFile#listFiles()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/provider/DocumentFile.html#listFiles()).

If I encrypt removable SD card from "Settings" -> "Lock screen and security option" -> "Encrypt SD card" and call DocumentFile#listFiles() again,
[I get **size 8192 bytes**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWDHk.png)!

As I suppose DocumentFile API should show me the same size for both encrypted and unencrypted cases. Device model Samsung Galaxy S7 with Android 7.0.

Comment: "As I suppose DocumentFile API should show me the same size for both encrypted and unencrypted cases" -- I would not make that assumption. `DocumentFile` itself is not really your problem; the storage provider for the removable storage is reporting 8192 bytes. As to why it is doing that, ask Samsung.

Comment: Thanks, Mark! Alredy done http://developer.samsung.com/forum/thread/documentfile-api-is-broken-on-encrypted-removable-sd-card-on-samsung-galaxy-s7/201/318140?boardName=SDK&startId=zzzzz~